# How do I shutdown the computer?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, shutdown

How to shutdown my computer using C#?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102567/how-to-shutdown-the-computer-from-c

Answer (score 10):

An easy way: Use Process.Start to run shutdown.exe.

```
  shutdown /s /t 0
```

Programmatic way: P/Invoke a call to [ExitWindowsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868(VS.85).aspx)

This would be the P/Invoke signature:

```
[DllImport("aygshell.dll", SetLastError="true")]
private static extern bool ExitWindowsEx(uint dwFlags, uint dwReserved);
```

Under all circumstances, the user running the code will need shutdown system privileges (normally not a problem, but an important point to remember).

Comment: Would you say a bit about how a person would choose between the two methods?  Or is it just easy vs not so easy?

Comment: I would nromally go for the second option in production software, as it gives you more control (shutdown reasons, etc). It takes a bit longer to implement, since I would need to lookup the correct flag and the signature.

Answer (score 5):

Different methods:

A.   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Shutdown", "-s -t 10");

B. Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)

http://www.csharpfriends.com/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=36953

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic33948.htm

C. System.Runtime.InteropServices Pinvoke

http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/251367-shutdown-my-computer-using-c

D. System Management

http://www.geekpedia.com/code36_Shut-down-system-using-Csharp.html

After I submit, I have seen so many others also have posted...

Comment: Although saying that I am still thinking - when would a person not just usethe first option?

Comment: I am not sure whether some one can disable rights for execution of shutdown.exe, in that case, one might need code to execute...

Comment: aren't B and D the same method? (WMI)

Comment: @Lucas, Eventhough both are WMI, invoking method names differ from each other.

Answer (score 4):

[WindowsController](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/class.qpx?id=7) is a c# wrapper class around ExitWindowsEx.

> Sometimes you need to restart or
>   shutdown the operating system from
>   your applications (for instance, after
>   the installation of a program). The
>   .NET framework offers you an indirect
>   way to restart the computer through
>   the Windows Management Instrumentation
>   (WMI) classes in the System.Management
>   namespace, however, there seem to be
>   some problems in their implementation.
>
> That's why we created the
>   WindowsController class that
>   implements some API functions to
>   restart and shutdown Windows. It
>   supports all the ExitWindowsEx modes
>   and it can also hibernate and suspend
>   the system.
>
> This class is available in C# and
>   VB.NET version. It can be compiled to
>   a .NET module or to a library to be
>   used from other .NET languages. Since
>   it relies on the Windows API, it will
>   not work on Linux or FreeBSD.
>
> (mentalis.org)

Comment: For those who want to know, the code is in open source under a variant of the BSD license.

Answer (score 1):

Use a variation of the "user logoff" code shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484278/log-off-user-from-win-xp-programmatically-in-c/484360).

That code uses the `ExitWindowsEx` API call.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess (untested):

```
Process.Start("shutdown", "-s -t 0");
```

Answer (score 0):

The hard way, works on laptops perfectly, although it takes some time:

```
Spawn a couple endless loops in more threads than cpu cores.
Wait for overheat which will automatically shutdown a computer.
```

:)

Comment: So many downvotes! Was it just me who found the answer amusing?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use InitiateSystemShutdown

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.initiatesystemshutdown

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    [DllImport( "advapi32.dll" ) ]
    public static extern bool InitiateSystemShutdown( string MachineName , string Message , uint Timeout , bool AppsClosed , bool Restart );

    [DllImport( "kernel32.dll" ) ]
    public static extern uint GetLastError();

    [DllImport( "kernel32.dll" ) ]
    public static extern uint FormatMessage( uint Flags , IntPtr Source , uint MessageID , uint LanguageID , StringBuilder Buffer , uint Size , IntPtr Args );



    public static void Main()
    {
        InitiateSystemShutdown(System.Environment.MachineName, "hello", 0, false, false);
        //InitiateSystemShutdown("localhost", "hello", 0, false, false);

    }
}
```