# Delay windows logoff (XP, Vista & 7)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Is there a known, reliable way to delay a user logging off once they have clicked the logout button? I am wondering about how I could go about delaying, or possibly cancelling the logout then logout through the application once the counter has expired.

Comment: People trying to shut their laptops down are not going to thank you for this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to stop the user from shutdown/logoff?

Comment: @StephenT, Because I'm an ass hole! Nah, its a business thing.

Comment: @Prisoner: "It's a business thing" is the best universal excuse for a developer asking something strange. I like it, especially since it often is a nice story hiding between the "business thing".

Comment: @Anders, I know. Its accepted though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a logout is about to occur, the Windows message `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` is sent to all applicaitons. An application can reply to this message with a negative answer, asking for the logoff to be cancelled.

From the [MDSN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376890(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Applications should respect the user's intentions and return TRUE. By
>   default, the DefWindowProc function returns TRUE for this message.
>
> If shutting down would corrupt the system or media that is being
>   burned, the application can return FALSE. However, it is good practice
>   to respect the user's actions.

In .NET this functionality is exposed by the [`SystemEvents.SessionEnding` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending.aspx). If you set the `Cancel` property of `SessionEndingEventArgs` to `true` requests the logoff being cancelled.

The logoff part has been asked before in [Log off user from Win XP programmatically in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484278/log-off-user-from-win-xp-programmatically-in-c).

Comment: Nitpicking, I know ;-), but the message is `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` (without the `S`) and after some seconds Windows will allow the user to kill those apps anyway, thus completing the logoff/shutdown.

Comment: Thats what I don't want to happen, the idea is that this box should remain on the top of all other windows. If that "kill processes" box then comes up it will be useless.

Comment: I thought the possibility to kill the apps was shown for apps not shutting down properly, but that the entire logoff was cancelled when an app asked for a cancel. If e.g. you have an unsaved excel file and  logs off, excel asks "really exit without saving". If you press "Cancel" there I think that the logoff is cancelled.