# Turn off windows box C#

Tags: c#, windows

I wonder if anyone know how to open this box with a c# command?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's in here somewhere: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: If you're just looking to log the user off:

[SO Logoff Programmatically][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484278/log-off-user-from-win-xp-programmatically-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add reference to Shell32.dll (COM -> "Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation") and use this code:

```
 Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
 shell.ShutdownWindows();
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a reference to C:\Windows\System32\Shell32.dll. After you do this, use this code:

```
Shell32.ShellClass sc = new Shell32.ShellClass();
sc.ShutdownWindows();
```

This will display the shutdown dialog as normal.